# Read unformated JSON file in Pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a simple json file into a dataframe. Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "apiName": "bctt-e-card-operations",
    "correlationId": "bctt-e-card-operations",
    "msg": "{   "MSG_TIP": "1261",   "MSG_VER": "02",   "LOG_SIS": "32",   "LOG_PERN01": "2122",   "LOG_NUMN01": "30108916",   "MSG_RESTIPA00": "0",   "MSG_IDE": "00216452708916",   "MSG_REACOD": "000",   "SAN_NUM": "000010X01941XXX",   "EXT_MOECOD": "978",   "SAN_SDIMNT": "00000043830",   "LOG_SINMOV": "C",   "SAN_SAUMNT": "00000043830",   "LOG_SINMOV": "C",   "SAN_SCOMNT": "00000043830",   "LOG_SINMOV": "C",   "SAN_SCODAT": "20220502",   "SDF_FORDAD": "0",   "CAR_PAGXTR": "0",   "CLI_LIMCRE": "0000000",   "SDF_AUTCAT": "000000000",   "LOG_SINMOV": "C",   "SDF_SLDDIV": "000000000",   "CLI_SDICSH": "000000000",   "LOG_SINMOV": "C",   "CLI_SDICPR": "000000000",   "LOG_SINMOV": "C",   "MSG_DADLGT": "0000" }"
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "msgFormat": "SIBS"
    "step": "response",
    "status": "0",
    "transTimestamp": "2022-05-02 16:45:28.487",
    "operationMetadata": {
        "msgType": "PAYMENT",
        "msgSubtype": "116100-02300",
        "accountId": "10X01941XXX",
        "cardNumber": "451344X063617XXX",
        "reference": "212230108916",
        "originalReference": null,
        "reversalReference": null,
        "timeout": false
        "flow": "PRT"
    },
    "error": {
        "errorCode": null
        "errorDescription": null
    }
}
```

Here is my code to read the file

```
file_location = "/mnt/test/event example.json"

df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(file_location, schema=schema)

display(df)
```

But as you can see the json file is missing some commas and also the 'msg' key has its value wrapped in quotes. This makes the dataframe return everything with nulls.
[image]

Is there a way to format the JSON, (in Pyspark because the file comes like that from the source), for removing the quotes and adding commas so the json is properly formated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could turn the JSON into a string and use Python RegEx sub() function to reformat the string.
Example:

```
 import re     
    json_string= " "contentType": "application/json",
        "msgFormat": "SIBS"
        "step": "response","
    x = re.sub("\"SIBS\"", "\"SIBS\"," , json_string)
    print(json_string)
" "contentType": "application/json",
        "msgFormat": "SIBS",
        "step": "response","
```

In this case, the function is looking for the value "SIBS" and replacing it with "SIBS",  .You might need to play around with it and use escape characters.

Comment: thank you ive tried it. unfortunately it doesnt work because the json file is not being read properly. when I save my dataframe and check the file it only has {}. its empty that is why its returning null but i dont understand why.

Comment: Since it's badly formatted you can't save it as a dataframe first. Try opening the file using Pyhton(open), saving it as a string and then do above actions.